# Session variable isn't carrying over to next page - session_start() has been started

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm not sure why my session variables are not being carried over to the next page.

session_start(); has been added to both pages, and if I dump the session on the first page, I get the array that I expect.

When I go redirect to the next page, the session_id remains the same, however the array is empty.

Here is the code:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $price=check_input($_POST["price"]);
  $number=$_POST['number'];
  $activity=$_POST['activity'];

  $_SESSION['price']=$price;
  $_SESSION['number']=$number;
  $_SESSION['activity']=$activity;

  $index_query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM activities WHERE people >= '$number' AND type='$activity' AND cost <= '$price' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;");
  $index_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($index_query);
  $activity_id=$index_fetch['id'];

  header("Location: activity.php?id=".$activity_id."");

}
```

Now, I added the below above my header redirect to see if the session was carrying anything, and It printed the correct information.

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
die();
```

However when I removed that and let it redirect to Page 2,:

```
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

It gives me an empty array.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: check session_id(). if the value is changing between loads, then you're somehow losing the session cookie and getting a NEW empty session each time.

Comment: plus, we don't know if your POST arrays are also empty or not. using error reporting will tell you that.

Comment: well, they might be empty, but it'd still create null values in session, and those'd show up in the var dump.

Comment: No idea. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Unable to replicate the problem.

Comment: Silly question but do you have cookies enabled on your browser? Also, check the session_id by printing it. Change the header redirection to a url for testing (since writing the session_id to screen will break header).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently. The session isn't passing through, you need to call the session_start on the page you are loading in order to reference the session variables.

Comment: they're doing that. Look at the bottom of their question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else looking, adding

```
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
```

beneath the

```
session_start();
```

Seemed to work for me!